# How to use the formula in negative roots?

Tags: complex-numbers, nested-radicals

This formula for nested-radicals: $\sqrt{A+\sqrt{B}}=\sqrt{\frac{A+C}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{A-C}{2}}$, works fine with $B > 0$, and with $A + \sqrt{B} > 0$, but doesn't work with complex numbers.

I tried to do a demonstration for imaginary numbers, but it did not work:

$\sqrt{A + \sqrt{B}i} = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}i$

$A + \sqrt{B}i = x + \sqrt{4xy}i -y$

$A + \sqrt{B}i = x - y + \sqrt{4xy}i$

$A = x-y, \sqrt{B}i = \sqrt{4xy}i \implies B = 4xy \implies x = A +y$

$B = 4(A+y)y \implies 4Ay +4y^2 \implies 4y^2 + 4Ay - B = 0$

$y = \dfrac{-4A \pm \sqrt{16A^2+16B}}{8} \implies \dfrac{-A\pm\sqrt{A^2+B}}{2}$, but this not work.

Comment: Why don't you think it works? $\sqrt{A+\sqrt{B}i} = \sqrt{(A+\sqrt{A^2+B})/2} + i\sqrt{(-A+\sqrt{A^2+B})/2}$ is true.

Comment: [Not work](https://es.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Csqrt%7B3%2B%5Csqrt%7B5%7Di%7D%3D%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(3%2B%5Csqrt%7B14%7D%5Cright)%7D%7B2%7D%7D%2Bi%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(-3%2B%5Csqrt%7B14%7D%5Cright)%7D%7B2%7D%7D), try with $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}i}=  \sqrt{\frac{\left(3+\sqrt{14}\right)}{2}}+i\sqrt{\frac{\left(-3+\sqrt{14}\right)}{2}}$

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sqrt%5B3+%2B+I*Sqrt%5B5%5D%5D+%3D%3D++++Sqrt%5B(3+%2B+Sqrt%5B14%5D)%2F2%5D+%2B+I*Sqrt%5B(Sqrt%5B14%5D+-+3)%2F2%5D).

Comment: So, symbolab have a wrong result. How do you know which of the two simple root you must multiply by the imaginary unit, that is to say, ¿Why do you multiply $\sqrt{(-A+\sqrt{A^2+B})/2}$ by $i$, instead of multiply $\sqrt{(A+\sqrt{A^2+B})/2}$ by $i$

Comment: And other doubt is that i got: $\sqrt{(-A-\sqrt{A^2+B})/2} + \sqrt{(-A+\sqrt{A^2+B})/2}$, how you get $\sqrt{(A+\sqrt{A^2+B})/2}$ without negative symbols

Comment: Remember your own calculation: $y = (-A\pm\sqrt{A^2+B})/2$ and $x = (A\pm\sqrt{A^2+B})/2$. You choose the $+$ signs so that $x$ and $y$ are both positive, and thus you don't have to worry about having negative numbers under the radicals.

Comment: Thanks, why you use the positive instead of negative result?

Comment: The $\sqrt{\,}$ function is not well-defined for negative arguments, since there is no consistent way to choose between $\sqrt{-1} = i$ and $\sqrt{-1}  = -i$.

Comment: Thanks eyeballfrog, can you post an answer